# Pyspark groupby column while conditionally counting another column

Tags: python, pyspark

I need help getting conditional output from pyspark when using groupBy. I have the following input table:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
|time|auth_orient|success|
+----+-----------+-------+
|   1|      LogOn|Success|
|   1|     LogOff|Success|
|   1|     LogOff|Success|
|   1|      LogOn|Success|
|   1|      LogOn|   Fail|
|   1|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|     LogOff|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|     LogOff|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Fail   |
|   2|     LogOff|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|     LogOff|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Fail   |
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
|   2|      LogOn|Success|
+----+-----------+-------+
```

The table below shows what I want, which only displays the logon stats:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
|time|Fail       |success|
+----+-----------+-------+
|   1|1          |3      |
|   2|2          |8      |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Overall I am trying to group on time and populate the new columns, preferably I would rather have the code populate the column names as I will not always have a complete list, with counts.

I know a portion of what I am trying to do is capable with MultilabelBinarizer, but that is not currently available in pyspark from what I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

Filter the data frame down to `LogOn` only first and then do `groupBy.pivot`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.filter(
    df.auth_orient == 'LogOn'
).groupBy('time').pivot('success').agg(F.count('*')).show()
+----+----+-------+
|time|Fail|Success|
+----+----+-------+
|   1|   1|      3|
|   2|   2|      8|
+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: This appears to work, but I am getting an error during runtime. (Error in opening FileSegmentManagedBuffer) It appears I need to configure the session's memory.